# What is the minimum amount of code that gets into the .elf image

Tags: gcc, linker, esp32, esp-idf

first a little context.

ESP32 using esp-idf framework latest version and having trouble fitting my code under the 1MB size limit with the default partitions. I noticed that a simple WiFi client (I mean really simple no HTTP requests or servers whatsoever) just takes up ~40% of the available space.

I was wondering at linking time what would be the minimum chunk of code that the linker will place in the output image file for any given dependency.

Is it a the file level (xxx.o) or is it able to somehow get any more granular?

Also is there any link switch that will list ALL references for any given .o/.a file? (i.e: where they depend on it)

Thanks in advance

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker is granular at the function/method and variable level. If a function or method or variable is not referenced then there's no need to include it in the linked binary.

You can check this out for yourself using the `objdump` program (you may need to install it on your system; there are other tools that can read .elf binaries that may already be installed).

Here's a simple program. This is in C++ using the Arduino framework but it uses the same toolchain as ESP-IDF since it's built on it. I included WiFi just go give it a little heft.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <WiFi.h>

void ignore_me() {
  Serial.println("this will never happen");
  Serial.println("this code won't even be linked in");
}

void setup() {
  WiFi.begin("foo", "bar");
}

void loop() {
}
```

Once it's built you can run

```
objdump --syms firmware.elf
```

to see a list of symbols. For instance, we can find the `setup()` function this way:

```
objdump --syms firmware.elf | grep setup
```

which returns:

```
40120cbc l     F .flash.text    00000032 setup_tcp
4012cd18 l     F .flash.text    00000013 __esp_stack_guard_setup
4010a2c8 g     F .flash.text    0000007d hostapd_setup_wpa_psk
400f8cb4 g     F .flash.text    0000032f esf_buf_setup
400d8f18 g     F .flash.text    0000008e ieee80211_setup_basic_htrates
400d9580 g     F .flash.text    000000da ieee80211_setup_phy_mode
4012edd4 g     F .flash.text    00000037 esp_setup_syscall_table
4008bb58 g     F .iram0.text    00000000 _frxt_setup_switch
400e02cc g     F .flash.text    00000141 ieee80211_send_setup
4013c320 g     F .flash.text    00000084 ieee80211_setup_lr_rates
400d8e4c g     F .flash.text    000000c6 ieee80211_setup_htrates
400d965c g     F .flash.text    00000134 ieee80211_setup_rates
40058cc8 g       *ABS*  00000000 __swsetup_r
400e2324 g     F .flash.text    00000101 ieee80211_setup_ratetable
400d04a8 g     F .flash.text    0000001c _Z5setupv
4013c3a4 g     F .flash.text    00000007 ieee80211_setup_rateset
40026c84 g       *ABS*  00000000 lmp_setup_cmp_handler
```

The symbol `_Z5setupv` corresponds to the setup function. The extra characters are due to C++ adding type information (For instance, the trailing `v` means its arguments are `void`).

Running

```
objdump --syms firmware.elf | grep ignore
```

will return nothing as the function `ignore_me()` wasn't included in the linked binary.

If we go back and modify `setup()` to call `ignore_me()` and run `objdump` again, we'll see something like:

```
400d04ac g     F .flash.text    0000001a _Z9ignore_mev
```

indicating that now `ignore_me()` is included in the binary since it's being called.

The `0000001a` is the size of the code associated with the symbol. You can use the output of `objdump` to find the largest functions in your binary; you may be able to rewrite it to eliminate some of them. (Spoiler: `printf()` and its relatives are often huge.)

You can also use `objdump` with `.a` and `.o` files.

Comment: Thanks a lot romkey for your clear and thorough explanation.!!

Comment: @Alex -you're welcome, happy it helped :) If it did help, accepting it as an answer will help other people know that it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

There's an article in the ESP-IDF docs how to [minimize the binary size](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/performance/size.html?highlight=size) of an ESP-IDF application. You can [list the size per-component](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/performance/size.html?highlight=size#component-usage-summary-idf-py-size-components) or even per file, if you want.

That being said, if you're using C++, try to avoid `iostream`, it tends to take a lot of space. You can use `printf()` instead.